# Finding punctuation and counting the number of each from the Unix Command line

Tags: unix, command-line, sed, tr

I want find all of the punctuation marks used my `.txt` file and give a count of the number of occurrences of each one. How would I go about doing this?? I am new at this but I am trying to learn!  This is not homework! I have been doing research on `grep` and `sed` right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ perl -CSD -nE '$seen{$1}++ while /(\pP)/g; END { say "$_ $seen{$_}" for keys %seen }'  sometextfile.utf8
```

As in

```
$ perl -CSD -nE '$seen{$1}++ while /(\pP)/g; END { say "$_ $seen{$_}" for keys %seen }' programming_perl_4th_edition.pod | sort -k2rn
, 21761
. 19578
; 10986
( 8856
) 8853
- 7606
: 7420
" 7300
_ 5305
’ 4906
/ 4528
{ 2966
} 2947
\ 2258
@ 2121
# 2070
* 1991
' 1715
“ 1406
” 1404
[ 1007
] 1003
% 881
! 838
? 824
& 555
— 330
‑ 72
– 41
‹ 16
› 16
‐ 10
⁂ 10
… 8
· 3
「 2
」 2
« 1
» 1
‒ 1
― 1
‘ 1
• 1
‥ 1
⁃ 1
･ 1
```

If you want not just punctuation but punctuation and symbols, use `[\pP\pS]` in your pattern.  Don’t use old-style POSIX classes whatever you do, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use sed, tr, sort and uniq (and no perl):

```
sed -E 's/[^[:punct:]]//g;s/(.)/\1x/g' myfile.txt | tr 'x' '\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

I did it this way (sed + tr) so it will work on both unix and mac. Mac needs an imbedded linefeed in the sed command, but unix can use `\n`. This way it works everywhere.

This will work on non-mac unix:

```
sed -E 's/[^[:punct:]]//g;s/(.)/\1\n/g' myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: That uses the broken, please-include-symbols-too-but-only-if-they-are-ASCII, old-fashioned POSIX definition of “punctuation”.  It makes no sense today. Do not use POSIX character classes. Use Unicode properties. POSIX properties suck.

Comment: If you think Mac isn’t Unix, you aren’t looking very closely.

Comment: @tchrist: are you telling us that POSIX character classes are mis-implemented (so if you're using a Unicode/UTF8 codeset, then the punctuation classes are mismanaged)?  Clearly, if the tools are told to work with a single-byte codeset, then feeding them multi-byte data will give misleading results.  But surely if the locale information says 'UTF8', then `[[:punct:]]` means 'punctuation in UTF8' and not 'punctuation in some SBCS'?  Can you identify where the problem is specified in the POSIX standard?

Comment: Sections [§3.89](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_89) and [§7.3.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01) seem to apply.  In the POSIX locale, then they may be so limited; in other locales, I don't see that the limitation is specified as you claim.  Implementations may be another issue altogether...they could easily be flawed.

Comment: @Jonathan: I promise you that in the en_US.UTF-8 locale under Darwin that the pipeline given in this answer most assuredly reports ASCII symbols as well as Unicode punctuation.  It also takes 15x the runtime that the Perl version I gave takes, and all that just to get the wrong answer.

Comment: What is an 'ASCII symbol that is not Unicode punctuation'?  Is that things like '@' and '#'?  It can't be that; your answer includes them...or is that deliberate?  (Probably not; what you show has `\pP` and not `[\pP\pS]`.)  It might also come down to what the questioner wants regarded as punctuation - and 'the beautiful thing about standards is that there are so many to choose from'.

Comment: I like the simplicity of your solution, however I did need to amend `sed -E 's/(.)/\1x/g'` to `sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1x/g'` (the `-e` is probably superfluous) for it to work on my lowly machine.

Comment: On reflection I found the solution might be condensed to `sed 's/[^[:punct:]]//g;s/\(.\)/\1\n/g' myfile.txt| sort | uniq -c`

Comment: This might even work at a pinch. `sed 's/./&\n/g' myfile.txt | sort | uniq -c| sed '/\w \w/d'`

Comment: @potong as I said, `\n` doesn't work on a mac, that's why I used the more complicated `tr` version. I like your concatenation of sed commands though - I have amended the answer to include this